# How to update an object in Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, parse-platform

So I am trying to create an iOS wait time app for an amusement park that utilizes parse.com to sync data across all instances of the app. What I want to happen is when an IBAction is run, an object will update with the new wait time. Here is the code I have in that IB Action.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"GrandCarousel"];

[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"9Fo5FBABpL" block:^(PFObject *updatedWaitTime, NSError *error) {
    updatedWaitTime[@"waitTime"] = localGrandCarouselWaitTime;
    [updatedWaitTime saveInBackground];
}];}
```

Thats the only code in that method. Whenever I run the method, the app crashes why?! Here is a picture of that class in the parse data browser: http://s8.postimg.org/y9ti6dzxx/Screen_Shot_2014_07_12_at_6_20_22_PM.png
(It won't let me add a picture directly yet) As you can see, I am very new to parse and pretty new to objective C. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: You need to provide more information - such as the exception or error message you are receiving - but you should at least check that error is nil before assuming that you have been able to retrieve the data

Comment: Heres the error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use nil for keys or values on PFObject. Use NSNull for values.'

Comment: So, it seems likely that `localGrandCarouselWaitTime` is nil. Check by setting a breakpoint and then work out why

Comment: Oh, never mind I got it, I created an if/else loop checking if the string was empty and then put the update code in the else portion.